# python - if conditions in string is true

Tags: python

python beginner here. My file contains lines that consists of conditions that are formatted just like a python if statement (without the if in the beginning and colon in the end). Example:

```
temperature < 40 and weekday == "Thursday" and (country != "Norway" or country != "USA")
(temperature != 30 or temperature != 35) and weekday == "Friday" and country == "Canada"
```

I want to write code that reads the lines as if they were if statements and prints True or False depending on if the conditions were met. I am thinking something along the lines of:

```
temperature = 35
country = "Canada"
weekday = "Friday"
file = open('output.txt', r)
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if line:
        # if conditions in string are met, print true
        print(True)
    else:
        # else print False
        print(False)
```

which should when run with above file lines should output

```
False
True
```

EDIT:

Would it be possible to reliably and consistently parse the file lines and process it, like how I'm assuming a python compiler would read an actual if statement?

Comment: You could use `if eval(line):`

Comment: `(country != "Norway" or country != "USA")` is always true. Delete this in 1 line: `and (country != "Norway" or country != "USA")`, and there are similar true condition in 2 line.

Comment: Simple but dangerous (because it executes arbitrary code from the file) is the built-in "eval" function.

Comment: Danger Danger: don't use `eval` @user56700

Comment: Can you show your output file?

Comment: @funnydman Is their example not enough?

Comment: Now  I understand what the file contains...

Comment: Don't use `eval` on entrusted, un-sanitised data. If you do, an error or malicious code in the data, could attack you. If you created the file, then consider importing it, else find a way to sanitise it.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, why you prefer don't use _**`eval`**_?

Comment: @George if you use `eval` to eval date, if will run the data as code. If the data is entrusted input. Then you are running entrusted code. The supplier of this data, can get you computer to do whatever they want.

Answer (score 2):

Alright so you've got a few basic issues, mostly forgetting to use `""` for strings such as in `country = Canada` and `weekday = Friday`. Other than that, you can use the `eval()` method, however, it is considered bad practice and you should try to avoid it.

```
temperature = 35
country = "Canada"
weekday = "Friday"
file = open('output.txt', "r")
lines = file.readlines()
for line in lines:
    if eval(line):
        # if conditions in string are met, print true
        print(True)
    else:
        # else print False
        print(False)
```

Note: Forgot to mention, you need `""` for the read specifier in `open()`.

Comment: I should also say I just fixed the code enough to make it work as intended, I'll edit in some good practices if you'd like.

Comment: Yeah my bad I also fixed them

Comment: why is eval bad practice?

Comment: It is good answer only if you don't need to print `True` or `False`

Comment: @finjasnappy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice

Comment: @finjasnappy See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/2476977) regarding eval.

Comment: @MarcoKurepa I'm curious about your recommended good practices here

Comment: `# if condition is True, then print True else if condition is False, then print False` 

Answer (score -4):

There are two concepts, selection (`if` statements), and conditions / boolean logic `<`, `or`, `and`, etc. You are trying to use the 2nd. You are correct you don't need the 1st.

When we program we don't write big programs that don't work, the fix them. We start with small programs that work, and then make them bigger. So let me start with a simple example.

`temperature < 40`

How do we print True if this is true, and False if it is false? The answer may surprise you.

`print(temperature < 40)`

Comment: It is good answer only if you need to print `True` or `False`

Comment: I believe this answers the question as asked. However, I think the question may be how do I **safely** read this input?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor This does not answer the question asked. If a file contains a condition to be checked, then using a print statement prints out the condition to be checked, not the result of checking this condition.

Comment: @Ben have you tried it?